# How can I skip the first and the last line of a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

Can anyone tell me please how I can skip the first and the last line a file.
I wrote two functions that return the first and the last line of a file 
but I need a the lines between the header and the tail !

```
function get_file_header($file)  {
  return fgets($file);
}  


function get_file_tail($file){
  while (( $line = fgets($file) )){
    $fin = $line;
  }
  return $fin;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please define *escape* in this context. Do you want to escape a string? Escape HTML tags?

Comment: "I wrote two function " - show what was writen

Comment: Edit your question instead of add comment please

Comment: *Escap*ing is different if the target is HTML, a JSON object, etc. It's impossible to answer to you without further information.

Comment: `get_file_tail ` is almost what you want. Run `fgets` once before the while, store the lines you get in the while in, say, an array, and when the while ends, trim the last element of the array. You can later rebuild the whole file from that array

Comment: @Korcholis can you pls write the solution ?

Comment: I can't add an answer while the question on hold. Anyway, I kinda gave you the solution in the comment. If you managed yourself to do the `get_file_tail` function on your own, just read [about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [how to remove the last item of an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php). You'll still need to control what happens when a file is 1 line long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the lines in an array first with [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then perform the removal with [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
function get_file_tail($filepath){
    // Read file as lines into an array
    $lines = file($filepath);
    // Remove first and last line
    $lines = array_slice($lines, 1, count($lines)-2);
    // Convert to string (if array is not useful for you) and return it
    return implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
}
```

Example call:

```
echo get_file_tail("http://websitetips.com/articles/copy/lorem/ipsum.txt");
```

Comment: The function is named `get_file_tail`, why does it remove the first and last line? It looks like it's not logical.

Comment: The function name is indeed strange, but it is the name chosen by the Asker, and his question was *"how I can skip the first and the last line a file"*.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved my problem doing this :

function get_file_details($file){

```
 $details = array();

 if ($file) {

   while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        array_push($details, $line);
   }

   fclose($file);
 }

 $info_file = array("header" => $details[0], "details" => remove_first_last($details) , "end" => end($details) );

 return $info_file;
```

}

function remove_first_last($array){

```
 array_shift($array);

 array_pop($array);

 return $array;
```

}